# How do I resolve a Python Syntax error print pointing to t?

Tags: python, printing, syntax

I am learning Python through MIT's EdX course. I tried the following and get a syntax error for `print` pointing at `t` in line 3. What am I doing wrong?

```
 x=int(input("Enter an integer")

if x/2==0

   print('') 

   print("Even")

 else 

    print('')

    print("Odd"))
```

Comment: Your indentation is messed up, and you're missing `:` on the `if` and `else` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you missed a parenthesis at this line:

```
x=int(input("Enter an integer")
#                              ^ add a ) here
```

Secondly, when you write the if statement, you should add a condition followed by a colon. The colon means that you are defining a block of code. You should indent the lines in the if block. Python is sensitive to indentations.

```
if x/2==0
print('')

print("Even")
```

Replace it with:

```
if x/2==0:

    print('')

    print("Even")
```

The same rule applies to the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

A couple suggestions, you likely want the modulus of 2 and not division by 2. Also, you can put in a new line without using a extra print statement (where, now actually, due to weird Python syntax you are not required to have a colon after the if/else blocks).

```
x=int(input("Enter an integer: "))

if x%2==0:
    print("\nEven")
else:
    print("\nOdd")
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks I figured out that I missed a parenthesis and also a colon or two! Here is the code that worked:

```
x=int(input("Enter an integer"))
if x/2==0:
   print('') 
   print("Even")
else: 
    print('')
    print("Odd")


Enter an integer5

Odd
```

Comment: You may want to consider whether it "works," or whether it "runs." It runs, but it is not "working" as intended.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your comment. Do you mean to say that code could run but not perform the intended outcome? Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you're trying to determine whether a number is "even" or "odd," then you want to check whether there's any "remainder" after dividing by 2. In programming the remainder is often given by the "percent" operator %. As such, even numbers can be found with if x%2==0. Pedantic note: Python actually calculates something known as the modulo with the % operator, there's a difference when you use negative numbers, but other languages give the remainder with the % operator; so if you use negative numbers in a % operation check your language's implementation.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I still have a lot to learn! I appreciate your patience and detailed explanation.